# jQuery text function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Can someone explain why the following is not working:
I have a textbox with the id: `result2` and with the jQuery function I try to access its text.

Somehow if I try to write that variable it says `undefined`

```
var x= $("#result2").text();
document.write(x);
```

Comment: Textbox = textarea or text input?

Comment: Then it should be `$("#result2").val()`

Answer (score 4):

If element with id `result2` is an `<input>` or a `<textarea>` you have to retrieve its value using `.val()`, `.text()` returns the inner text of the element.

```
var x = $("#result2").val();
alert(x);
```

Comment: +1 because obviously from your comment you found the problem first.

Comment: Thanks, I need ages to write every time the ` symbol, because I need to do `alt + 96` :P